# Polly V8 CircuitBreaker behavior is different, the circuit gets stuck open

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker

I have attempted to upgrade to V8 of Polly but now the status of a CircuitBreaker becomes stuck as open indefinitely.

My classic `AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync` continues to work following a Nuget download of the V8 Polly package but then I tried to adopt the substantial V8 api changes including `ResiliencePipelineBuilder`, `CircuitBreakerStrategyOptions` and `CircuitBreakerStateProvider`. Now I am experiencing the stuck open circuit problem.

The V8 problem only occurs when I skip repeated calls to `_resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(...)` with the following logic:

```
if (_circuitBreakerStateProvider.CircuitState == CircuitState.Open)
{
    // return fallback value indicating remote service is unavailable but
    // the CircuitState never progresses to HalfOpen 
    return null;
}
await _resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... );
```

The equivalent logic with a classic circuit breaker works as expected:

```
if (_breakerPolicy.CircuitState == CircuitState.Open)
{
    return null;
}
// after the configured durationOfBreak timespan expires we get here with circuit at HalfOpen
await _breakerPolicy.ExecuteAsync( ... );
```

It seems that the circuit state will not progress from *Open* to *HalfOpen* without further invocation of `_resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync()`

---

**UPDATE #1**

As requested by @Peter Csala.

Here is my pipeline config, it is designed for a fail-fast requirement in a low traffic situation. There is no direct DI configuration for the `ResiliencePipeline`. The Pipeline is declared and held in an application `RpcFacade` class that is itself a singleton, a breakpoint confirms the pipeline is built once and all testing is through single user manual UI testing of a Blazor server application.

```
services.AddSingleton<RpcFacade>();

_breakerState = new CircuitBreakerStateProvider();

var builder = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder<List<LiveAgentInfo>>().AddCircuitBreaker( new CircuitBreakerStrategyOptions<List<LiveAgentInfo>>
{
    FailureRatio = 0.1,
    SamplingDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 ),
    MinimumThroughput = 2,
    BreakDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 15 ),
    ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder<List<LiveAgentInfo>>().Handle<RpcException>(),
    StateProvider = _breakerState
} );
```

---

**Update #2**

I have enabled additional Polly logging. This logs an entry *"Resilience event occurred. EventName: 'OnCircuitOpened'"* as the Circuit transitions from Closed to Open on the second failing GRPC call to a remote GRPC service that is not reachable.

Logging of `_circuitBreakerStateProvider.CircuitState` just before the `_resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... )` confirms the Closed to Open transition so the `_circuitBreakerStateProvider` instance is maintaining a valid observation of the CircuitBreaker's internal state.

---

**Update #3**

Further testing reveals another insight. In the original code above I showed how I was returning a fallback value when `CircuitState` == `CircuitState.Open` in order to avoid calling `_resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(...)` during the Open 15 second window.

If I always call `_resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... )` even when the circuit status is open then I get `BrokenCircuitExceptions` during the open window, then after 15 seconds the circuit breaker lets through a remote call which triggers an `RpcException`. At this point I see a log entry *"Resilience event occurred. EventName: 'OnCircuitHalfOpened' in the log"*.

It seems the circuit breaker only identifies that it has reached a `HalfOpen` state condition during `resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... )`. It then makes the external grpc call expressed in my lambda which fails and the state returns to Open. From the external perspective of the `CircuitBreakerStateProvider` the state appears stuck at Open.

As a workaround, I can return a fallback value in my `BrokenCircuitException` catch, this fails fast and is outcome I wanted.

Comment: Interesting. Could please share with us the definition of the circuit breaker policy and strategy?

Comment: @PeterCsala - See above as requested. I have enabled additional Polly logging. This logs "Resilience event occurred. EventName: 'OnCircuitOpened'" as the Circuit transitions from Closed to Open on the second failing GRPC call to a remote GRPC service that is not running. Logging of _circuitBreakerStateProvider.CircuitState just before the _resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... ) confirms the Closed to Open transition so the _circuitBreakerStateProvider instance is maintaining a valid observation of the CircuitBreaker's internal state.

Comment: @PeterCsala - Further testing reveals another insight. In the original code above I showed how I was returning a fallback value when CircuitState == CircuitState.Open in order to avoid calling _resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... ) during the Open 15 second window. If I always call _resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... ) then I get BrokenCircuitExceptions during the open window, then after 15 seconds the circuit breaker must do a remote call which triggers an RpcExcetion. I also see "Resilience event occurred. EventName: 'OnCircuitHalfOpened' in the log".

Comment: To continue my last comment... It seems the Circuit breaker only identifies that it has reached a HalfOpen state during resiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync( ... ). It then makes the external grpc call expressed in my lamda which fails and the state returns to Open.

From the external perspective of the CircuitBreakerStateProvider the state appears stuck at Open.

I can return a fallback value in my BrokenCircuitException catch, this fails fast and is outcome I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing all these. Could you please add your observations to the question? I'm currently from my mobile and I'll dig into this problem on Monday. Until then have a great weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: V7's `CircuitState` property's getter is more complex than V8's.

---

In order to understand why **V7 does** and *why V8 does not* transition from `Open` into `HalfOpen` state without invoking `ExecuteAsync` we need to look a bit under the hood. It won't be painful I promise.

In both cases we have a controller class which is stateful and does the heavy-lifting. The policy/strategy uses the controller to ask for the state transitions.

### V7

Here we have a [`CircuitStateController`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/release/7.2/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitStateController.cs) with a bunch of fields.
The important ones from this question perspective:

```
protected readonly TimeSpan _durationOfBreak;
protected long _blockedTill;
protected CircuitState _circuitState;
...
protected readonly Action _onHalfOpen;
```

- The `_blockedTill` captures a date time until when the CB must remain in `Open` state before it could transition into `HalfOpen`

  - Its value is calculated when the CB breaks by using SystemClock and `_durationOfBreak`
- The `_onHalfOpen` is called ONLY when the `CircuitState` is evaluated

```
public CircuitState CircuitState
{
    get
    {
        if (_circuitState != CircuitState.Open)
        {
            return _circuitState;
        }

        using (TimedLock.Lock(_lock))
        {
            if (_circuitState == CircuitState.Open && !IsInAutomatedBreak_NeedsLock)
            {
                _circuitState = CircuitState.HalfOpen;
                _onHalfOpen();
            }
            return _circuitState;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this important from the question perspective? Because in your early exit condition you are directly asking the Circuit Breaker to please re-evaluate the circuit state (`_breakerPolicy.CircuitState == CircuitState.Open`). That's why it transitions from `Open` to `HalfOpen`.

This **also** means that V7 does not transition from `Open` to `HalfOpen` automatically. If your CB breaks and you don't assess the `CircuitState` either directly or via the `ExecuteAsync` it will remain in `Open` state (*and your `onHalfOpen` won't be triggered*).

### V8

In the new version the `_onHalfOpen` user delegate is called only from the `ScheduleHalfOpenTask` method:

```
private Task ScheduleHalfOpenTask(ResilienceContext context)
{
    _executor.ScheduleTask(() => _onHalfOpen!(new OnCircuitHalfOpenedArguments(context)).AsTask(), context, out var task);
    return task;
}
```

and this method is only being called from the `OnActionPreExecuteAsync`.
Here is an excerpt of the method:

```
public async ValueTask<Outcome<T>?> OnActionPreExecuteAsync(ResilienceContext context)
{
    ...

    lock (_lock)
    {
        // check if circuit can be half-opened
        if (_circuitState == CircuitState.Open && PermitHalfOpenCircuitTest_NeedsLock())
        {
            _circuitState = CircuitState.HalfOpen;
            _telemetry.Report(new(ResilienceEventSeverity.Warning, CircuitBreakerConstants.OnHalfOpenEvent), context, new OnCircuitHalfOpenedArguments(context));
            isHalfOpen = true;
        }

        exception = ...

        if (isHalfOpen && _onHalfOpen is not null)
        {
            task = ScheduleHalfOpenTask(context);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

As you have already figured out this `OnActionPreExecuteAsync` is called ONLY by the [strategy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly.Core/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerResilienceStrategy.cs#L32) whenever its `ExecuteCore` is being executed.

---

The `CircuitBreakerStateProvider` [does not perform too much things](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly.Core/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerStateProvider.cs#L32C5-L32C96) whenever you retrieve the circuit state:

```
public CircuitState CircuitState => _circuitStateProvider?.Invoke() ?? CircuitState.Closed;
```

The invoked method [is specified](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly.Core/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerResilienceStrategy.cs#L18C9-L18C67) inside the `Initialize` call (from the strategy).

```
stateProvider?.Initialize(() => _controller.CircuitState);
```

The controller's `CircuitState` property's getter is super simple.

```
public CircuitState CircuitState
{
    get
    {
        EnsureNotDisposed();

        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _circuitState;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it does not perform any check whether it should transition to `HalfOpen` or not.

### Summary

- In case of V7 the cb policy transitions from `Open` to `HalfOpen` because you access the `CircuitState` and the getter might change the state of the circuit breaker.
- In case of V8 the cb strategy does not transitions from `Open` to `HalfOpen` automatically because the state provider simply returns the current state of the controller and does NOT induce any state change.

I hope it was not painful and the description clarified certain things. :)

Comment: Thankyou for your thorough investigation of my question, I am relieved the outcome was interesting rather than a simple matter of developer API misuse. At one level the new V8 behavior conforms to the principal that a property getter should not change the internal state of something as complex as a circuit breaker, however it could be argued the implementation of the V8 CircuitBreakerStateProvider is wrong because it reports the historic state its circuit breaker rather than the effective point in time state. No matter as long as this is documented. I can proceed using BrokenCircuitExceptions.

Comment: @camelCase Yeah, you are right. Neither of them feels accurate. Please feel free to file an issue on Polly's github and it might happen that your requested change might be accepted and delivered in the next minor release (8.1.0).

Comment: @camelCase Do you have any further questions? If not can I ask you to close this thread by accepting this post as the answer.

Comment: Oops have just done so.